# Disable JFrame when a new JFrame is opened

Tags: java, swing, jframe, modal-dialog, jdialog

I am trying to disable the "main" `JFrame` when the new frame pops up. I want it so you can not click or drag anything on that frame. I tried making the new frame a `JDialog`, but that did not disable the other frame. I also looked at the other post about this, which suggested to make it a `JDialog` but it still does not work. I really need help doing this please. thanks. This is the codeIi am using to make the `JDialog`, is their any problems with it?

```
editDialog=new JDialog(IntroScreen.frame);
```

`IntroScreen.frame` represents the "main" frame.

Comment: gosh, this has never been asked before...

Comment: is this sarcasm or not..? can't tell

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have set for [JDialog#setModal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20boolean%29) or [JDialog#ModalityTypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html), maybe with  [Dialog.ModalityType APPLICATION_MODAL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html#APPLICATION_MODAL)

Comment: Yep, the correct answer -- the dependent window should be a JDialog, not a JFrame. Either that or swap views via a CardLayout.

Comment: I will research into this and try to implement into my project :)

Comment: @CaptainGh0st: you accepted the wrong answer. This one is the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use multiple `JFrame`s you could use the method [`setEnabled()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) when you open the other `JFrame`.

```
frame.setEnabled(false);
```

Otherwise you should go with [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and its method [`setModal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20boolean%29).

Comment: Thank you sir, I have no idea how I didn't find this method when I was going through the methods. -__- THANKS.

Comment: You chose the 'right' answer to the wrong question.  The (easy) way forward is pointed out by HFOE & mKorbel.  Multiple frames will cause you more stress.