# Disabling other action while a JFrame is open

Tags: java, swing, jframe, modal-dialog, jdialog

I was wondering if it was possible to disable all other action when a JFrame is opened in Java.

Just like this?

[image]

Is there easy code for this?

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: Thanks, i'm using Card layout for most of my program, but this was an exception :)

Answer (score 4):

This has been asked many times and the answer is always the same: use a modal JDialog or JOptionPane (which is a version of a modal JDialog), not another JFrame.

For example, please check out mKorbel's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627078/disable-jframe-when-a-new-jframe-is-opened?rq=1).